# Vb.Net script to connect to SQL Server and write returned stored procedure results into Excel file no longer working

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

This use to be able to run quite smooth. But it is not longer working and I cannot figure out why it will not write data or if it even is able to connect to the database. It is not catching and printing the message box so it must not be failing?

Here is an example of the SQL Server database table I am trying to load into an Excel file:

[image: Database Image]

For anyone wanting to test as well:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Submitted_Jobs_List]
(
    [Recnum] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfService] [date] NULL,
    [JobName] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
    [JobID] [int] NULL,
    [Superintendent] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [ReportRun] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO tbl_Submitted_Jobs_List (DateOfService, JobName, JobID, Superintendent, email) 
VALUES
    ('2018-10-25', 'Chase Test Job', 2233, 'Forms', chase@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Chase Test Job', 2233, 'Forms', chase@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Chase Test Job', 2233, 'Forms', chase@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Trent Test Job', 1234, 'Test', cayers@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Trent Test Job', 1234, 'Test', cayers@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Trent Test Job', 1234, 'Test', cayers@test.com),
    ('2018-10-25', 'Trent Test Job', 1234, 'Test', cayers@test.com)

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]
--Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DateOfService, JobName, JobID, Superintendent, email
    FROM dbo.tbl_Submitted_Jobs_List 
    ORDER BY DateOfService, Superintendent
END
```

I am still trying to get better at troubleshooting pieces of code. My VB.Net isn't very strong. But with the above T-SQL code, I trimmed out some joins to make the stored procedure easier to test with for this post. The result table is still the same for me.

Here is the VB.Net code I am executing. I am connecting to SQL Server and running the stored procedure `Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs`.

I am then trying to parse through the results and load into an Excel file I create at the path shown below on the C drive for test.

I just want to verify if the code is working fine, then I may be looking at a connection issue with my MSSQL Server.

If anyone does have any better techniques on writing more efficiently to an Excel file that may require less reader actions I am always happy to hear about criticisms.

Thank you!

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration

Namespace WorkflowActivity.Scripting.SDKScript

    Public Class Script1
        Inherits RAScriptClass92

        Protected Overrides Sub Execute()

            Try
                Dim path As String = "C:\Test\import\Reports\" & "Report_Superintendent.csv"
                Dim sw As StreamWriter
                Dim myServerAddress As String = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"
                Dim myDataBase As String = "TestDB"
                Dim myUsername As String = "sa"
                Dim myPassword As String = "password"

                If Directory.Exists(path) = False Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
                End If

                If File.Exists(path) = False Then
                    sw = File.CreateText(path)
                    sw.Flush()
                    sw.Close()
                End If

                sw = File.AppendText(path)

                Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=" & myServerAddress & _
                                             ";Database=" & myDataBase & _
                                             ";User ID=" & myUsername & _
                                             ";Password=" & myPassword & _
                                             ";Trusted_Connection=False;")

                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]", con)
                con.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60

                sw.WriteLine("Date of Service,Job Name,Job ID,Superintendent,Super Email")

                While reader.Read()

                        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}"",""{4}""", _
                        reader.GetString(0).Trim(" "), _
                        reader.GetString(1).Trim(" "), _
                        reader.GetString(2).Trim(" "), _
                        reader.GetString(3).Trim(" "), _
                        reader.GetString(4).Trim(" ")))

                End While

                sw.Flush()
                sw.Close()
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()  

            Catch ex As Exception

                Msgbox("Cannot connect, Error:" & ex.Message)

            End Try

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code?  It would appear not, so you should be doing that first, before posting here.  You should already know whether the connection is successful because the specific exception that is thrown would tell you so.  Also, if you set a breakpoint and step through the code then you'll see exactly what line the behaviour first deviates from your expectation.

Comment: If you're saying, without actually saying, that it works when debugging but not in the environment it's intended for then add some tracing code, i.e. output the state of the application at various stages and then you can what stage it gets to and where the state is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly generate `.csv` files from the SQL server. try the following:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -E -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON EXEC DBNAME.[dbo].[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > D:\outputfilename.csv'
```

*Please replace the names as per your environment.*

Comment: This looks like it should run correct but I am getting the error:  Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server[2].  I checked and all the TCP/IP Pipes are enabled for all Client Protocols.  Server is not found or not accessible.

I replaced your DBNAME and the Path at the end.  Was there anything else I am missing for replacing?   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -E -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON EXEC PullSageData.[dbo].[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > C:\Laserfiche\import\Reports.csv'

Comment: try to pass the servername as well after SQLCMD with -S option.

Comment: I added the server with -S and it looks like the output is NULL.  I verified and the csv file is being created where expected.  Thank you so much!  Much cleaner to run this within SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure how it was working before, but you have to ExecuteReader before you can get rows from it:

```
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()  

            While reader.Read()

                    sw.WriteLine(String.Format("""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}"",""{4}""", _
                    reader.GetString(0).Trim(" "), _
                    reader.GetString(1).Trim(" "), _
                    reader.GetString(2).Trim(" "), _
                    reader.GetString(3).Trim(" "), _
                    reader.GetString(4).Trim(" ")))

            End While

            sw.Flush()
            sw.Close()
```

I would also suggest you use the Using pattern such as:

```
Dim sConnection As String = "server=     (local);uid=sa;pwd=PassWord;database=DatabaseName"
         Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        Con.Open()
        Using Com As New SqlCommand("Select * From tablename", Con)
            Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
                If RDR.HasRows Then
                    Do While RDR.Read
                        txtName.Text = RDR.Item("Name").ToString()
                    Loop
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
```